# Onclick Div inside form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 4 `div`s in my form like below:

```
<div class="col-sm-6" >
    <div class="bunch">

        <h4>title</h4>

        <span>price $</span>
        <span class="time">text</span>
        <span class="button">text</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

user click is handled with this JS script:

```
 $(".bunch").click(function () {
     if ($(".bunch_wrap_center").hasClass("active"))
     {
         $(".bunch").removeClass("bunch-active");
         $(this).addClass("bunch-active");

            $(".bunch_wrap_center.active").siblings(".last_forms").find("input, select").removeAttr("disabled");
         $(".register .last_forms select").css("background", "#fff");
     }
 });
```

How to create a name for each of these `div`s to send it in form submit?

Comment: ...are you asking for `div`s to function like checkboxes in a form?

Comment: What form?  What "name"s?  It's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: Bwolfing Yes want it to be like checkbox

Comment: If you are trying to do what David says, why not try to use the sibling selector in CSS. Add a label and checkbox to your form. Make the checkbox hidden with css. then use `checkbox:checked + .bunch` and `checkbox + .bunch` to style things accordingly. No javascript required and the data will be submitted as you wish in the form. No magic needed. No *bad* HTML needed. No using divs as checkboxes.

Comment: can you please tell me how to implement this with code above?

Comment: Here is a very simple example. https://jsfiddle.net/nmarbct8/. If you need some more explanation on "why" any of that works, I can clarify.

Comment: Your code does not match your HTML (there's nothing with a class `bunch_wrap_center`, for example). Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [set an attribute](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#keyvalue) with 2 parameters:

```
$(".bunch").attr("name", "yourValue");
```